# Making a data frame from list of tables with different column names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a long list of tables that I need to turn into a data frame. The issue is that different tables have different column names. All names range from 1 to 5, but for example some tables only have column 2, others have columns 4 and 5, while others have the five columns.

An example of the data is:

```
> head(bffrsTbls)
[[1]]

   2    5 
 711 1781 

[[2]]

   2    5 
1168 1530 

[[3]]

   1    2    3    5 
 390  471  904 1237
```

I already tried `bffrsTbls %>% purrr::map_df(., dplyr::bind_rows)` but the values in the resulting data frame don't correspond to the column names of each table.

The result that I'm looking for is a data frame as this one, with columns val1 to val5 corresponding to columns 1 to 5 of each table and an extra column showing the number of the list element where the data of that specific column came from:

```
ListElmnt   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5
1           NA     711    NA     NA     1781
2           NA     1168   NA     NA     1530
3           390    471    904    NA     1237
```

Comment: Is it a `vector` or data.frame` as list element

Comment: it is vector:
 $ : 'table' int [1:2(1d)] 711 1781
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "2" "5"
 $ : 'table' int [1:2(1d)] 1168 1530
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "2" "5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `list` elements to `tibble` by looping through the `list` with `map` and change it to a single data.frame

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(bffrsTbls, ~ .x %>%
                     as.list %>%
                     as_tibble)
```

---

If we also need all the combinations, `enframe` the `list` elements to a 2 column tibble, and `spread` the output dataset to 'wide' format

```
bffrsTbls %>%
  map_df(enframe, .id = 'ListElmnt') %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(paste0('val', name), levels = paste0("val", 1:5))) %>% 
  spread(name, value, drop = FALSE)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  ListElmnt  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1            NA   711    NA    NA  1781
#2 2            NA  1168    NA    NA  1530
#3 3           390   471   904    NA  1237
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
xtabs(values ~ ListElmnt + ind, do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, 
      lapply(bffrsTbls, stack), ListElmnt = seq_along(bffrsTbls))))
```

#### data

```
bffrsTbls <- list(structure(c(`2` = 711, `5` = 1781), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = list(
c("2", "5")), class = "table"), structure(c(`2` = 1168, `5` = 1530
 ), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = list(c("2", "5")), class = "table"), 
   structure(c(`1` = 390, `2` = 471, `3` = 904, `5` = 1237), .Dim = 4L,
   .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "5")), class = "table"))
```